# lex - how to match escape characters for / and \

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

i'm looking for a way to way to match / and \ 
for example: if i get the string "hello\sir/!" i'd like to get hello\sir/!

Comment: What did you try and in what way did it fail to work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `(.*\\.*\/.*)`:

`.*` Should match every single character or nothing

`\\` Should match a backslash (Two of them since you need to escape)

`\/` Should match a common slash (With a backslash since you need to escape)

`(...)` Should be the capture group

Watch out for multiline tags (Depending on the text you want to match with)...

https://regex101.com/r/HY0NXI/3